# Sort the Data from JSON as per the Date and Set Tableview section Title as date and following data as per the Date

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift4.2

**JSON File:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "msg": "User Phone Usage",
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-19",
            "val": [
                {
                    "ride_id": 44,
                    "date": "2019-12-19 09:32:19",
                    "total_km": null,
                    "startTime": "2019-12-19 09:32:19",
                    "endTime": "2019-12-19 09:37:08",
                    "rides": 0
                },
                {
                    "ride_id": 43,
                    "date": "2019-12-19 09:28:16",
                    "total_km": null,
                    "startTime": "2019-12-19 09:28:16",
                    "endTime": "2019-12-19 09:32:23",
                    "rides": 0
                },
                {
                    "ride_id": 42,
                    "date": "2019-12-19 09:28:12",
                    "total_km": null,
                    "startTime": "2019-12-19 09:28:12",
                    "endTime": "2019-12-19 09:29:13",
                    "rides": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-13",
            "val": [
                {
                    "ride_id": 2,
                    "date": "2019-12-13 08:14:34",
                    "total_km": 12.64,
                    "startTime": "2019-12-13 08:14:34",
                    "endTime": "2019-12-18 03:49:43",
                    "rides": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-12",
            "val": [
                {
                    "ride_id": 1,
                    "date": "2019-12-12 06:59:26",
                    "total_km": 101.36,
                    "startTime": "2019-12-12 06:59:26",
                    "endTime": "2019-12-18 03:07:00",
                    "rides": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So i have to set the tableview section title as (date) and show the event occurred on that particular date.

**Below is the sample image i have to achieve**

[image]

Section title is date and total km, rides are the row that i want to populate as per the date specified. API data is saved in model class and not in dictionary format so need some solution where i can sort the data and display it on the table view.

**Model class:**

```
class ShowDetails
{

    var startRideDateTime:String?
    var rideID:Int?
    var endRideDateTime:String?
    var totalKM:Double?
    var rides:Int?


    init(rideID: Int?,totalKM: Double?, startRideDateTime: String?, endRideDateTime: String?, rides: Int?) {
        self.rideID = rideID
        self.totalKM = totalKM
        self.startRideDateTime = startRideDateTime
        self.endRideDateTime = endRideDateTime
        self.rides = rides
    }


}
```

**Viewcontroller code:**
showdetailsArray is the saved array from API Response

```
func grouping()
    {

        let groupData = Dictionary(grouping: self.showDetailsArray){ (element) -> String in
            return (element.startRideDateTime ?? "")
        }

        groupData.forEach { (key) in
            print("VALUES")
            print(groupData.values)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Tried some solutions but i am not able to achieve it. but right now i have just created a model class which saves. the data from API and also tried out Grouping method of dictionary but unable to extract the values.

```
let groupData = Dictionary(grouping: self.showDetailsArray){ (element) -> String in
            return (element.startRideDateTime ?? "")
        }

        groupData.forEach { (key) in
            print("VALUES")
            print(groupData.values)
        }
```

Comment: Add the code that you've tried here.

Comment: i will edit the question. so it would be more clear

Comment: why not use Codable

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShowDetails {
    var startRideDateTime:String?
    var rideID:Int?
    var endRideDateTime:String?
    var totalKM:Double?
    var rides:Int?

    init(rideID: Int?,totalKM: Double?, startRideDateTime: String?, endRideDateTime: String?, rides: Int?) {
        self.rideID = rideID
        self.totalKM = totalKM
        self.startRideDateTime = startRideDateTime
        self.endRideDateTime = endRideDateTime
        self.rides = rides
    }
}

class myData {
    let date: String // this value should not be optional as you are sorting on basis of this
    let value: [ShowDetails]?

    init(date: String, value: [ShowDetails]?) {
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
    }
}

// set your data here
var data:[myData] = []

// this is the array sorted according to date
data.sort(by: { $0.date > $1.date })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** for data parsing and the later sorting it based on date.

The models that you can use,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var data: [Model]
}

struct Model: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let val: [Ride]
}

struct Ride: Decodable {
    let rideId: Int
    let date: String
    let totalKm: Double?
    let startTime: String
    let endTime: String
}
```

Now, parse the data like,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    var response = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    response.data.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In the above code, use `response` as your `tableView's` `dataSource`.

Comment: i have tried both of the code and was unable to achieve as it sorts the data comparing to next date with it time so it adds the news section if the time is changed so 2 sections of same dates occurs in table view. but thanks for the ans.

I have got the solution which i will add.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution to the Ans if anybody needs:
After saving the data into class model at the end you can add this code to Sort.

```
func groupingByDate()
        {
            let groupData = Dictionary(grouping: self.showDetailsArray){ (element) -> String in
                return (element.startRideDate ?? "") //It fetches the element from model class array and set as key of dictionary and other elements as values
            }


            groupData.keys.forEach { (key) in

                let values = groupData[key]
                twoDArray.append(values ?? []) //twoDArray is a two dimensional Array           
            }
               //reloadTableview if you want
        }
```