# Format JSON data to display in tableview with section in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2023-10-12 15: 50: 45+0000",
    "Text": "Description",
    "Title": "Recommendation"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2023-10-13 15: 50: 45+0000",
    "Text": "Description",
    "Title": "Recommendation"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2023-10-14 15: 50: 45+0000",
    "Text": "Description",
    "Title": "Title"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2023-10-12 15: 50: 45+0000",
    "Text": "Description",
    "Title": "Recommendation"
  }
]
```

I'm getting the above JSON and I wanted to create a model to display data in tableview cell with section header.

I have tableview cell to display title and description and same day cells in one section.

**UI**

**-> Same day Date on Section title.**

**-> Title and description on each cell.**

I tried with this code able to all list of dates now have to filter and place same day data in one section.

```
struct Elements: Codable {
        let date, text, title: String

    }

    var allDates = [Date]()

    func formattedModel(model: [Elements]) {
        for data in model {
            allDates(data.date)
        }
        // Here in allDates we have list of all dates
        // Now here we need to create date section list of data.
    }
```

UI should look like below only title and description on cell.

[image]

Comment: You need to group. If the elements are already sorted, you can use Swift Algorithm and `chunck` method to group the elements per the same day. See https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md or do it manually, with `reduce(into:_:)` or using `Dictionary.group(by:)` first...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573487/sort-the-data-from-json-as-per-the-date-and-set-tableview-section-title-as-date

Comment: Are you using `UITableView` ?

Comment: @koen Yes UITableView Need list of data to display on it.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift?